# A magic way to solve binomial integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I find a method on a book to solve integrals like:
$$ \int x^m{\left ( a+bx^n \right )}^p{\mathrm{d} x} $$
It says that this integral can only be expressed by finite combinations of elementary functions when:

1. p is an integer.
2. $ \frac{m+1}{n} $ is an integer. Then use $ a+bx^n=z^s $, s is the denominator of p(reduced fraction)
3. $ \frac{m+1}{n}+p $ is an integer. Then use $ ax^{-n}+b=z^s $.

But this book didn't tell me why it's like that and how did they get it, I need an answer for these two questions.

Comment: Did you try applying the substitutions and seeing what happens when the given conditions do/don't hold?

Comment: They are Chebyshev's binomial integrals and the substitution of variables you write transforment the corresponding integrals in elementary known integrals (if you manage well the changement). For all the other possible cases of binomial integrals you do have impossibility of elementary integration.